# BreezeJS unable to parse EDM metadata with more than one namespace?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I am writing a web application with Breeze, OData, WebAPI, and Angular (BOWA) using the integrated WebAPI ASP Identity schema. When breeze consumes the $metadata it is unable to finish and gives a 'null' error and fails. I disabled the ASP Identity to test and it works fine. Is Breeze unable to address more than a single namespace? The namespace is posted below. Are there any known work arounds to this? (OData v3)

```
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework">
<ComplexType Name="IdentityUserRole">
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="RoleId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</ComplexType>
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserClaim">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ClaimType" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ClaimValue" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
<ComplexType Name="IdentityUserLogin">
<Property Name="LoginProvider" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ProviderKey" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</ComplexType>
</Schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the section "Correcting the namespace for EdmBuilder" on this page: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/odata-server

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the ODataConventionModelBuilder with Breeze.EdmBuilder and the all models are under a single namespace!